# tufte-book and gb4e and footnotes / sidenotes

Tags: footnotes, incompatibility, linguistics, tufte, gb4e

When using the `tufte-book` class (and other `tufte` classes, I imagine), footnotes / sidenotes seem to break the instant you load the gb4e package.

This compiles correctly, and displays a sidenote as designed.

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\begin{document}
This is text.\footnote{This is a sidenote.}
\end{document}
```

This throws two errors, one about 'missing number, treated as zero', the other about an illegal unit of measure. The sidenote is displayed incorrectly - there's one [ off to the side as a sidenote, and then the rest is placed in the main text preceded by a ].

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\begin{document}
This is text.\footnote{This is a sidenote.}
\end{document}
```

What is going on here? Does `gb4e` try to redefine footnotes in a way that's incompatible with `tufte-latex`? Since `gb4e` has nothing to do with footnotes, ostensibly, I'm confused as to why there's a conflict at all. Is there any way to get around this and use `gb4e` in a `tufte-book` document, or would that require rewriting one or the other package? (or is it not worth the effort?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `gb4e` package does modify the footnote code to number examples in footnotes correctly. Usually this doesn't interfere with other footnoting modifications, but the `tufte` classes make quite substantial changes. So you need to redefine the `tufte` footnote with the `gb4e` modifications included.

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\noautomath
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@footnotetext[2][0pt]{%
  \marginpar{%
    \hbox{}\vspace*{#1}%
    \def\baselinestretch {\setspace@singlespace}%
    \reset@font\footnotesize%
    \@tufte@margin@par% use parindent and parskip settings for marginal text
    \vspace*{-1\baselineskip}\noindent%
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel{%
       \csname p@footnote\endcsname\@thefnmark%
    }%
    \color@begingroup%
       \@noftnotefalse\setcounter{fnx}{0}%
       \@makefntext{%
         \ignorespaces#2%
       }%
    \color@endgroup%
  }%
\@noftnotetrue}%
\makeatother
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
\ex A regular example
\end{exe}
\lipsum[1]\footnote{A footnote\begin{exe}\ex A footnoted example\end{exe}}
\begin{exe}
\ex A regular example
\end{exe}
\lipsum[2]\footnote{A footnote\begin{exe}\ex A footnoted example\end{exe}}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Yep, that works beautifully. Thank you, sir!